# In an Eclipse Project, how to get simplelogger.properties file automatically included if using SLF4J Simple Logging?

Tags: java, eclipse, slf4j

I have downloaded and unzip SLF4J 1.7.12 on my PC at `D:/SOURCE/ProgramsInstalled/slf4j-1.7.12` folder.

I want to work with **Simple Logging** of SLF4J so I am concentrating on these 2 files:

1. `slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar`
2. `slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar`

In eclipse I want to have the above 2 files treated as 1 Library so I can include that library in any project if I need it.

So in Eclipse I created a new User Library named `SLF4J_1.7.12_SIMPLE` and include the above 2 files in it.

Now in any project where I want to use **Simple Logging** of SLF4J, I can just include this User Library `SLF4J_1.7.12_SIMPLE`.

But in any such project I also want to include the `simplelogger.properties` file. Is it possible to automatically include this file in a project if that  project include User Library `SLF4J_1.7.12_SIMPLE`? If yes then how?

Assume `simplelogger.properties` file is located in `D:/SOURCE/ProgramsInstalled/slf4j-1.7.12` folder.

Thanks